# Unwrap an array into rows in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, database, postgresql, row

What is the fastest way to unwrap array into rows in PostgreSQL? For instance,

We have:

```
a
-
{1,2}
{2,3,4}
```

And we need:

```
b
- 
1
2
2
3
4
```

I'm using:

```
select explode_array(a) as a from a_table;
```

where explode_array is:

```
create or replace function explode_array(in_array anyarray) returns setof anyelement as
$$
    select ($1)[s] from generate_series(1,array_upper($1, 1)) as s;
$$
```

Is there any better way?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Use [unnest](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html). For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test( p_test text[] )
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  SELECT id FROM unnest( p_test ) AS id;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE
  COST 1;
```

Answer (score 95):

unnest --> expand an array to a set of rows

```
unnest(ARRAY[1,2])
1
2
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/c774a/24

Comment: **e.g. `select unnest( '{1,2}'::int[] )` or `select unnest( '{a,b}'::text[] )`** will return the row columns with proper type ... more stuff here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-array.html

Answer (score 18):

If you have a table `users_to_articles` like:

| user_id | articles |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {1,2} |
| 2 | {6,2,7} |

And need to explode the articles array so to obtain:

| user_id | article_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 7 |

You could run something like that:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "users_to_articles" (
  "user_id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  "articles" INT[]
);

INSERT INTO "users_to_articles" ("articles")
VALUES ('{1,2}'), ('{6,2,7}');

SELECT
  "user_id"
, "article_id"
FROM "users_to_articles", unnest("articles") AS "article_id";
```

Here is a working sqlfiddle:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c26742/1

Answer (score 0):

You can use [unnest()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) to unwrap an array into a set of rows.

For example, you can unwrap the array of `INT[]` type into a set of rows as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT unnest(ARRAY[1,2,3]::INT[]);
 unnest
--------
      1
      2
      3
(3 rows)
```

*Memos:

- The type of unwrapped values are `INT`(`INTEGER`).
- You can omit `::INT[]`, then the type of unwrapped values are still `INT`(`INTEGER`).

And, you can unwrap the array of `VARCHAR[]` type into a set of rows as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT unnest(ARRAY['John','David','Robert']::VARCHAR[]);
 unnest
--------
 John
 David
 Robert
(3 rows)
```

*Memos:

- The type of unwrapped values are `VARCHAR`(`CHARACTER VARYING`).
- You can omit `::VARCHAR[]`, then the type of unwrapped values are `TEXT`.

And, you can unwrap the array of `RECORD[]` type into a set of rows as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT unnest(ARRAY[ROW('John','Smith'),ROW('David','Miller')]);
     unnest
----------------
 (John,Smith)
 (David,Miller)
(2 rows)
```

*Memos:

- The type of unwrapped values are `RECORD`.
- You must use `ROW()` instead of `::RECORD[]`to create the array of `RECORD[]` type otherwise there is [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77952634/how-to-create-the-array-of-rows-by-hand-in-postgresql).