# Create a Stored Procedure to Delete Records from employee(first table) and orders(second table) based on input params (id, arrayOfNo [])

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

I have two tables, `employees` (company_id, employee_num) and `orders` (employee_num, order_description).

If user sends procedure params `company_id`, `employe_num` (1, [911,912]) then if `employees` table has more employee numbers with id 1 then we should delete additional employee numbers rows like if it has [911,912,913] employee numbers with 1 then it should delete the row from 913 as emp_num and delete all the records in orders (table two) where emp_num is 913

ex(Procedure):

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION deleteEmployeeOrders(P_company_id bigint, orders_array  arrayType[] ) RETURNS INT AS $$
 DECLARE
         orders_array  arrayType;
 DECLARE
         order  arrayType;
 DECLARE
         status_code integer;
 BEGIN
   status_code:= -1;

   FOR line IN (SELECT * FROM employees where company_id = p_company_id)
         LOOP
             if exists(select * from  employees where emp_num = order.emp_num not in orders_array)
THEN
                delete from employees where employee_num = order.employee_num;
                DELETE FROM orders WHERE employee_num = order.employee_num;
         END LOOP;
   status_code = 1;
   return status_code;
 END;
 $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

For example

```
 :select deleteEmployeeOrders(1,[911,912])
```

it should delete 913 as emp no in row table1, and delete all the rows in table2 where emp_num 913

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, it sounds like you want to delete all employee (and related order) records for a given company_id.  Is that correct?  If so, you can use two simple DELETEs:

```
-- Delete all orders related to employees for given "company_id"
DELETE FROM orders 
WHERE employee_num IN (
  SELECT employee_num 
  FROM employees 
  WHERE company_id = p_company_id
);

-- Delete employees for given "company_id"
DELETE FROM employees
WHERE company_id = p_company_id;
```

They should be done in the same transaction, so they either all work or all fail.  Also you should do the "orders" DELETE first so you can reference the employees in the employees table.

If this isn't what you need, then please explain a little more exactly what you're looking for.  I don't quite follow the logic in your example for deleting employee 913 if you only specify employees (911,912).

**Updated**

Modified the DELETE statements to run against employee_num values NOT present in arrayOfNo array:

```
-- Delete all orders related to employees for given "company_id"
DELETE FROM orders 
WHERE employee_num IN (
  SELECT employee_num 
  FROM employees 
  WHERE company_id = p_company_id
  AND employee_num <> ALL(arrayOfNo) -- Get employees NOT IN arrayOfNo list
);

-- Delete employees for given "company_id"
DELETE FROM employees
WHERE company_id = p_company_id
AND employee_num <> ALL(arrayOfNo) -- Get employees NOT IN arrayOfNo list
;
```

Again, the two statements should be run as a single transaction.  Let me know if that works.

Comment: ex: In Table employees currently with id 1 we have three employees. but when pass only 2 employee nums. these two records should remain the one which i didnot pass and which exist in table should be deleted.

Comment: And i am gonna pass the array list of employee numbers to the procedure. so it has to check the array too

Comment: So, you just want to delete the records for emp_num values that are NOT in the orders_array, correct?  If so, you can modify the DELETE statements I put above with this logic.  If you can do it like that (using just two batch DELETE statements), that's better than doing it in a LOOP, which results in multiple individual DELETE statements.

Comment: i have below query.
I have to insert values [{name:'ravi',age;20},{name:'kumar',age;22}]. The stored procedure should take this array as input and store this as individual columns like below.

Table

name - age
ravi   20
age    22

Comment: above json array should do like (insert into tablename values(''ravi',20);

Comment: I suggest you unnest your array to convert it to a recordset.  Then you can manipulate that recordset and INSERT it into your table however you want.  Take a look at this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309568/unwrap-postgresql-array-into-rows

You can cursor through the recordset (in which case you should use a stored procedure/function).  You can also do it in one statement, as a batch Upsert (Insert/Update).