# Convert array to rows in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-8.4

If I have something like this in SQL statement `('A','B','C')`, how do I convert it into a column with multiple rows like this

```
col
---
 A
 B
 C
```

I cannot change the way that string is created (as it is injected into SQL query from external program). For example, I cannot make it as `['A','B','C']` (replace with square brackets). I could wrap anything around it though like `[('A','B','C')]` or whatever.

Any help?

**UPDATE 1**

I have PostgreSQL 8.4.20

Comment: @jpmc26 No, not really. In my case, the constraint is the exact `('A','B','C')` string I have to deal with.

Comment: I retracted the close vote before you said anything, but it apparently didn't delete the comment.

Comment: Your version of PG has not received security updates [for almost 4 years](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). It's *extremely* important that you update to a supported version; this will also make a wide range of new features available to you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unwrap postgresql array into rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309568/unwrap-postgresql-array-into-rows)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create an `ARRAY` from `VALUES` and then unnest it:

```
SELECT 
    unnest(ARRAY[col_a, col_b, col_c]) 
FROM 
    (VALUES('A','B','C')) AS x(col_a, col_b, col_c)
```

Result:

```
| unnest |
|--------|
|      A |
|      B |
|      C |
```

Edit: you could also tweak [jspcal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50476342/4860123) by using dollar quotes (`$$`) like this so you can concatenate your string into the SQL statement:

```
  SELECT * FROM regexp_split_to_table(
    regexp_replace(
      $$('A','B','C','D','foo')$$,
      '^\(''|''\)+', '', 'g'),
      ''','''
    );
```

Comment: This is very creative. I am doing more testing but look promising... :D Is it possible to have variable number of values? Like `('A','B','C','D','E')` without knowing ahead of time?

Comment: This solution only works for a fixed number of columns. I am still searching for a more dynamic solution.

Comment: I've added a solution based on @jspcal's answer but using dollar quotes `$$` to quote your string.

Comment: Awesome. We are getting to somewhere. I got the first row as `('A` though. There is extra `('`... Still monkeying around here.

Comment: I works correctly on this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/22696). But it uses PG9.3 instead of 8.4.

Comment: My final insane solution `select unnest(string_to_array(cast(trim(regexp_replace(replace($$( 'A','B','C','D','foo' )$$, '\',\'',' '), '[(\')]','','gi')) as text), ' '));` LOLZ

Comment: @HP. `select unnest(cast(translate($$( 'A','B','C','D','foo' )$$, '()''', '{}"') as text[]));` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=f8ab56a87c453d2af27ff0fced6b4fb8

Answer (score 2):

The built-in [`regexp_split_to_table`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-string.html) function will do this for you. Since you plan to inject it directly without escaping, use [`$$`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html) ([dollar quoting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html)) from [thibautg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50476945/235354).

```
select * from regexp_split_to_table(
    regexp_replace($$('A','B','C')$$, '^\(''|''\)+', '', 'g'),
    ''','''
);
```

Comment: If I do `select regexp_split_to_table('A B C', E'\\s+');`, it will work. But my original string is `('A','B','C')`. So how to make it into `'A B C'`?

Comment: You could strip the extraneous chars with `regexp_replace`.

Comment: I cannot change it to `(''A'',''B'',''C'')` but I can make it surrounded with quotes for example `"('A','B','C')"`

Comment: Take a look at the answer above that passes the original text to a function.

Comment: @HP. When you say you "cannot change it", this makes no sense. If you have it hard coded, you can change it to anything you want. If it's being passed in from somewhere else, you could *still* modify the string on the fly using other function calls. Additionally, this answer doesn't double the quotes *in the string*; it's just *escaping* the single quotes so that the string contains what you specified your input is.

Comment: @jpmc26 Welcome to Enterprise Software dude where 99% of things you don't have control. I am just a DBA monkey.

Comment: @jspcal So `('A','B','C')` is like a VARIABLE from external software. It's like a string that is being parsed into the final query as-is.

Comment: @HP. [`REPLACE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#id-1.5.8.9.7.2.2.32.1.1): `REPLACE(my_incoming_var, $$'$$, $$''$$)`. If you have control over *any* code here (which you must for your question to make even 1% sense), then you can do whatever the heck you want to the string.