# Postgres - split list into rows

Tags: postgresql

I have a table containing lists like so:

```
['string1','string2']
['string3']

etc
```

And would like to split each element into its own row.

I've tried converting to an array by doing a regex replace to remove the square brackets :

```
SELECT
ARRAY[regexp_replace(
          regexp_replace(place_id, '\[', '')
         , '\]', '')::text]
from place_ids
```

Which gives i.e.:

`{'string1','string2'}`

However I'm not sure how to split these out. I've tried using `unnest` :

```
SELECT
unnest(
    ARRAY[regexp_replace(
              regexp_replace(place_id, '\[', '')
            , '\]', '')::text]
)
from place_ids
```

But this seems to just remove the array brackets:

`'string1','string2'`

I was hoping to get something like:

```
'string1'
'string2'
'string3'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [Convert array to rows in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50476306/convert-array-to-rows-in-postgres)

```
drop table if exists data ;
drop sequence if exists data_seq;
create table data (
                      rid integer,
                      data varchar
);
create sequence data_seq start with 1;

insert into data (rid, data) VALUES
(1, '[''string1'',''string2'']'),
(2, '[''string3'']')
;

select rid, regexp_split_to_table(regexp_replace(data, '\[|\]', '', 'g'), ',')
from data
;
```

result:

```
1,'string1'
1,'string2'
2,'string3'
```