# How to create the array of rows by hand in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, row, recordtype

I'm trying to create the array of rows with `::RECORD[]` or `::RECORD`  by hand as shown below:

```sql
SELECT ARRAY['(John,Smith)','(David,Miller)']::RECORD[];
```

Or:

```sql
SELECT ARRAY['(John,Smith)'::RECORD,'(David,Miller)'::RECORD];
```

But I got the error below:

> ERROR:  input of anonymous composite types is not implemented

Actually, I could run the query without `::RECORD[]` or `::RECORD` below but the type is `TEXT[]`:

```sql
SELECT ARRAY['(John,Smith)','(David,Miller)'];
```

So, how can I create the array of rows by hand?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is kind of already in your question: you could use [`row()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS) constructors. [Demo:](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZOsWsh1e)

```sql
select array[row('a',1,true),row('b',4,false)];
```

| array |
| --- |
| {"(a,1,t)","(b,4,f)"} |

```
select pg_typeof(array[row('a',1,true),row('b',4,false)]);
```

| pg_typeof |
| --- |
| record[] |